# Momentary freezes about every 60 seconds

Tags: 13.04

I have just switched from OpenSuse to Ubuntu (the only reason is poor repositories - I got tired of installing everything from tar-balls). OpenSuse KDE worked flawlessly. Off-topic OS 7 does too.

However, Ubuntu 13.04 after all updates keeps freezing about every minute. The time differs between occasions. It halts just for a fraction of a second, too quick to notice, but music crackles, and compressed video looses its tracks and covers with errors until a scenecut.

I don't know what is responsible, the logs are clear.

Tried to:

- change audio card,
- switched to Nvidia drivers and back,
- paused all unneeded daemons.

Didn't help much.

Any ideas where to look? I am experienced in Linux, just new in Ubuntu.

Comment: I have installed unstable nvidia drivers 313 instead of 310 and the problem seem to be gone. Not closing yet in case it comes back.

Comment: OK, now, *after* the driver update, the bug is localised only in mplayer front-ends. The trouble is SMplayer is a video player I'd want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the fact that, while my Ubuntu was installed on SSD, my videos and music where residing on WD Green HDD. These HDDs are known for their very aggressive power saving features. So, HDD sometimes managed to fall into suspend between video frames, and then player could not retrieve the next frame in time. 
I have sidestepped the  problem by turning on video caches for local files.

Comment: Is that local file caching a media player setting? What media player are you using? I know how to change this in VLC, but not on others.

Comment: I use SMplayer. Caching is in Preferences -> Performance. However, as I have said, this is only a temp solution. The proper one will be to tweak FS (which is BTRFS in my case) so that it either IO to disk every 5 seconds, or cache files fully into RAM and let HDD sleep peacefully. If I succeed, I will write how.